# Does the Nikon Coolpix 900 need the exact CF card specified in the package?

Tags: nikon, coolpix, compactflash

I was given a Nikon Coolpix 900 (1998 model) but there was no CompactFlash memory card. Basically in so many words the original package came with a: EC-8CF 8MB CompactFlash card but now I am questioning whether or not I need that *exact* model (likely an eBay purchase at this point) or can I get a different model with similar size? For context it becomes harder to work with above 200 Mb.

Comment: The card supplied with the initial Coolpix 900 cameras was only 4MB. At highest quality settings this was room for only six images.

Comment: The question made me thinking - both SD and CF memory cards derive their interface from the good old IDE standard, so it should be easy to make a CF adapter for SD cards. A quick search revealed that these adapters are commercially available and fairly cheap. Worth a try, instead of looking for an obsolete memory type.

Answer (score 2):

Even though there are several variations of CF cards (multiple versions of CF which are backward and forward compatible, IDE, CFast) the camera definitely expects generic Compact Flash. You are definitely not going to have any issues with different brand of cards and different sizes.

The only reason there was a 8MB card in the package is for test purposes or basic usage. Almost all cameras had a small card in the package. 8MB is small even by 1998 standards.

Comment: However since the camera is quite old there is likely an upper limit to the size of CF cards it can support. FAT32 is likely not supported so this would limit the camera to 2GB max CF cards (that may be hard to find these days).

Comment: In most cases larger cards can be used, but the camera will only recognize 2GB. If larger cards are much cheaper than finding older "new" 2GB cards, then it makes perfect sense to use a larger card and live with the size limitation. One might need to use a computer that can reformat the card to the camera's file system, presumably FAT16. Note that per page 74 of the [P900 Manual](https://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/coolpix/CP900rm.pdf) the camera's internal file system is limited to a maximum of 999 images on the memory card.